# add android platform not working

Tags: android, cordova

I want to add android platforms to my project but when i write "phonegap platform add android" in my project directory, i see an error:

```
'platform add android' is not a node in   
 "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js" command. See node
 "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js"
```

I searched but i dont know what is problem? I run check_reqs from ".cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin" and cmd opened and not write anything and aftet second closed.

my phonegap is 3.4 and i add these to my path:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Program Files\Java\ant\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin;
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools;
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `phonegap build android` directly. It will generate platform-specific files.